# Action on post publish

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development, actions, publish

I want to do something when a post is published (doesn't matter if updated [draft -> publish] or just created)

In my plugin I tried different actions to try this. I tried the following code to detect when which event is triggered:

```
function new_post() { file_put_contents('debug.log', 'new_post', FILE_APPEND); }
function publish_post() { file_put_contents('debug.log', 'publish_post', FILE_APPEND); }
function pending_post() { file_put_contents('debug.log', 'pending_post', FILE_APPEND); }
function draft_post() { file_put_contents('debug.log', 'draft_post', FILE_APPEND); }
function auto_draft_post() { file_put_contents('debug.log', 'auto_draft_post', FILE_APPEND); }
function future_post() { file_put_contents('debug.log', 'future_post', FILE_APPEND); }
function private_post() { file_put_contents('debug.log', 'private_post', FILE_APPEND); }
function inherit_post() { file_put_contents('debug.log', 'inherit_post', FILE_APPEND); }
function trash_post() { file_put_contents('debug.log', 'trash_post', FILE_APPEND); }
function save_post() { file_put_contents('debug.log', 'save_post', FILE_APPEND); }

add_action('new_post', 'new_post', 10, 2);
add_action('publish_post', 'publish_post', 10, 2);
add_action('pending_post', 'pending_post', 10, 2);
add_action('draft_post', 'draft_post', 10, 2);
add_action('auto-draft_post', 'auto_draft_post', 10, 2);
add_action('future_post', 'future_post', 10, 2);
add_action('private_post', 'private_post', 10, 2);
add_action('inherit_post', 'inherit_post', 10, 2);
add_action('trash_post', 'trash_post', 10, 2);
add_action('save_post', 'save_post', 10, 2);
```

But it seems like this is only working if I plan a post to be published in the future. In this case only 'publish_post' and 'save_post' is triggered.

Do I need to configure something or why are the other ones not working?

Comment: Is your aim to simply trigger some code when a post is published?

Comment: @ChristineCooper exactly.
To specify: I want to call an external API when a post is published, but this should not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your aim is to trigger code when a post is published, as in, the `post_status` of the post is set to `publish`, then you can hook into `save_post` like this:

```
function cc_publish_wpse_263985( $postid ) {

    // check if post status is 'publish'
    if ( get_post_status( $postid ) == 'publish')  ) {

        // do something here

    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'cc_publish_wpse_263985' );
```

Comment: This is what I've tried, but it does not work, if I manually publish a post. It is only triggered if I plan a post which is published somewhen in the future.

Comment: If you manually publish a post, the code above should work. Can you kindly confirm if you are *manually* publishing a post?

Comment: Oh, I found the problem! I'm writing something to a file to debug. When the post is published via cron the file is created in the main-dir (where wp-cron.php is), but when I publish it manually the file is created in subfolder "wp-admin" where I didn't look.

Comment: Ah right, glad it worked out! =D